# MySQL SUM data in column "A" when data in column "B" matches

Tags: php, mysql

My table is as follows:

```
Year    Week   Points
2007     1       20
2007     1       15
2007     2       15
2007     2       15
2008     1       8
2008     1       10
```

I want my outcome to be:

```
Most Points: 35 (2007 Week 1)
2nd Most Points: 30 (2007 Week 2)
3rd Most Points: 18 (2008 Week 1)
```

I'm using:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(POINTS) ";
$query .= " FROM SCHEDULE";
$query .= " AND WEEK = '1' ";
$query .= " AND YEAR = '2008'";
```

Is there a way to get the points SUM w/o having to run separate queries for each week and year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a simple query. Have you tried this? :

```
select `Year`, `Week`, sum(`Points`) as Total_Points
from myTable
group by `Year`, `Week`
order by sum(`Points`) desc
limit 3
```

Comment: Thanks! Group By and Limit 3 really helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` for this, for example:

```
SELECT YEAR, MONTH, SUM(POINTS) FROM SCHEDULE GROUP BY WEEK,YEAR
```

That will then form groups of items with the same `WEEK` and `YEAR`, then sum across those.

Comment: Thanks! Group By is the key!

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
SELECT
    SUM(Points) total,
    CONCAT(`Year`, ' Week ', `Week`)
FROM
    SCHEDULE
GROUP BY
    `Year`,
    `Week`,
ORDER BY
    total DESC
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't use CONCAT, but I'll keep that in mind for later.